# Irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be prime. Is there a specific form for $p$ in which

(1) $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

(1) $x^2-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Thanks!

Comment: It is  well known that $x^2+1$ is irreducible mod. an odd prime $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$.

Comment: Thank you so much, @dan_fulea :)

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard :)

Answer (score 2):

First note that $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ is always reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, for any positive prime integer $p$. For the remaining part, $x^2+1=x^2-1$ when $p=2$, and for odd prime integers, see the answer given by [mathworker21](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/366088/mathworker21) of the following posted question [Prime integer p such that -1 is is a square mod p](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408129). Indeed, $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if $x^2+1$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if $-1\equiv p-1$ mod $p$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.